# Смена параметров символической ссылки PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

У меня есть скрипт на который я хочу создать ссылку и поместить ее на рабочий стол.
Пусть файл скрипта хранится по пути `C:\app\script.ps1`.
Я использую следующую команду для создания ссылки:

```
New-Item -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\startApp.lnk -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value C:\app\script.ps1
```

Ссылка успешно создается, но не запускается, т.к. для работы скрипта требуются файлы которые лежат рядом с ним, а ссылка в качестве рабочего каталога использует рабочий стол, а не место расположение исходного файла.
Вопрос: как изменить рабочий каталог ссылки, или изначально создать ссылку с верным рабочим каталогом?

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы путаете средства. Судя по имени файла **startApp.lnk** Вы пытаетесь создать [ярлык](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BA_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)). В тоже время работаете с [символической ссылкой](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/fileio/symbolic-links). Это - разные вещи. Определитесь, что Вам нужно и каким средствами хотите достичь этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае создавать нужно не символическую ссылку, а ярлык:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$c = $Shell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\user\Desktop\startApp.lnk")
$c.TargetPath = "C:\app\script1.ps1"
$c.WorkingDirectory = "C:\app"
$c.Save()
```